# Saltstack and making states generic

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

Need some help as I am a little stuck now. The end goal is to have a state that would be generic and allow us to push our pem cert files to any server requiring it and to different dirs for each server. I hope that makes sense. In other words, I dont want a separate state for each server to distribute pem files.

What I have thus far:

Main state to be included in relevant servers(I have changed the specific details for variables to something else):

```
{% if 'custom_id' in pillar.get('the_custom_id')  %} 
{% set theuser = 'relevantuser' %}
{% set certpath = '/path/to/certs' %}
{% elif 'another-custom_id' in pillar.get('the_custom_id') %}
{% set theuser = 'relevantuser' %}
{% set certpath = '/path/to/certs' %}
{% else %}
{% set theuser = 'relevantuser' %}
{% set certpath = '/path/to/certs' %}
{% endif %}

{{ certpath }}:
  file.directory:
    - user: {{ theuser }}
    - group: {{ theuser }}
    - file_mode: 600
    - dir_mode: 755
    - makedirs: True
    - recurse:
    - user
    - group
    - mode

{% for cert_type in pillar.get('pem_certs', {}) %}
{{ certpath }}{{ cert_type }}.pem:
  file.managed:
    - context:
        cert_type: {{ cert_type }}
    - mode: 600
    - source: salt://path/to/file/filename
    - template: jinja
{% endfor %}
```

The contents of the source of file.managed above:

```
{{ pillar['pem_certs'][cert_type] }}
```

The pillar file in the pillar.get function would then contain the pem key.

```
pem_certs:
  ca-cert:
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE---------
    etc
```

The saltstack environment is up and running and fully working. The same route was taken in adding the rsa_id private keys for minions which is working fine. The file.directory works fine and creates the dir and applies the correct user accordingly.

From the debug I can see that the file.managed state is not being rendered and I dont know why.

Debug output from running the state:

```
[DEBUG   ] Rendered data from file:       /var/cache/salt/minion/files/base/path/to/state.sls:

/path/to/certs:
  file.directory:
    - user: theuser
    - group: theuser
    - file_mode: 600
    - dir_mode: 755
    - makedirs: True
    - recurse:
          - user
          - group
          - mode

[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded config.get
```

Currently I am assuming that the pillar.get is not retrieving or cannot retrieve pem_certs. Is there a way to test this specifically?

Can anyone out there help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently do `{% for cert_type in pillar.get('pem_certs', {}) %}` which returns an empty dict if not present in the minion's pillar - i guess this is the first thing to start with.

For debugging you want to **know** if there is data available for your minion by doing something like `salt 'minionid' pillar.get pem_certs`. if this does not show up the pillar data, check your pillar's top.sls. Is the pillar data applied to your minion properly?

Further you should consider using `{% for cert_type, cert_data in pillar.get('pem_certs', {}).iteritems() %}` - if doing so, you can directly hand over the content to the context of your `file.manage` template and no longer need to query for pillar data inside of the template anymore.